# Effect of a capacitor in a transmission line

Tags: capacitor, transmission-line

What will the consequences be if I add a load capacitor in parallel with the load resistance in a simple transmission line?

Here is the circuit.

[image: Circuit with transmission line]

Comment: For finding the "waveform" of the reflected wave, just write the reflexion coefficient at the receiver side with Laplace values of the impedances, and then use invlaplace to find reflected wave vs time. Add it to incident wave with the delay... or simulate it.

Comment: The consequences in what respect? Are you calculating the VSWR? The reflection coefficient? The time domain response? The dollar cost of building the system?

Comment: The reflection coefficient and the time domain response.

Comment: The Falstad circuit simulator has a T.Line for you to try this very scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simulation will show this picture, comparing behavior when the line load is a **matched** resistor (Generator is also matched, it should always) ... and when a capacitor is added.
One can see that fast transitions are "lost" and that voltage at the receiver is ok after some time (please note that the "constant" of the exponential is then \$(ZL*Zo/(ZL+Zo))*CL=0.5*Zo*CL\$ and not \$ZL*CL\$ only (remember \$ZL=Zo\$).

[image]

And here is the "mathematical" background.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *What will the consequences be if I add a load capacitor in parallel
> with the load resistance in a simple transmission line?*

A simple transmission line will have a simple characteristic impedance that is resistive therefore, by adding a capacitor, you will get signal reflections at the load-end of the line due to a mismatch of load and characteristic impedance.

That reflection will travel back to the source-end and may or may not get reflected again back to the load-end (depending on resistor \$R_g\$ and the mismatch it presents to the characteristic impedance of the transmission line.

I can tell you what generally happens but, I can't tell you what the knock-on consequences might be (such as damage to the sending-end driver or data corruption). These are all possibilities (as is the possibility that the corrupted signal received may still be usable).